# How to wait until a sound file ends in vlc in Python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x

I have a question in vlc in python

```
import vlc

sound = vlc.MediaPlayer('sound.mp3')

sound.play()

# i wanna wait until the sound ends then do some code without 
time.sleep()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import time, vlc

def Sound(sound):
    vlc_instance = vlc.Instance()
    player = vlc_instance.media_player_new()
    media = vlc_instance.media_new(sound)
    player.set_media(media)
    player.play()
    time.sleep(1.5)
    duration = player.get_length() / 1000
    time.sleep(duration)
```

### After edit

## That exactly what I wanted, thanks everyone for helping me ..

Answer (score 3):

for wait util end of vlc play sound, except your:

```py
    player.play()
    time.sleep(1.5)
    duration = player.get_length() / 1000
    time.sleep(duration)
```

other possible (maybe **more precise**, but **CPU costing**) method is:

```py
# your code ...

Ended = 6
current_state = player.get_state()
while current_state != Ended:
  current_state = player.get_state()
  # do sth you want
print("vlc play ended")
```

refer :

- [vlc.State definition](http://www.olivieraubert.net/vlc/python-ctypes/doc/vlc.State-class.html)
- [vlc.Instance](http://www.olivieraubert.net/vlc/python-ctypes/doc/vlc.Instance-class.html)
- [vlc.MediaPlayer - get_state](http://www.olivieraubert.net/vlc/python-ctypes/doc/vlc.MediaPlayer-class.html#get_state)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the get_state method (see here: https://www.olivieraubert.net/vlc/python-ctypes/doc/) to check the state of the vlc player.

Something like

```
    vlc_instance = vlc.Instance()
    media = vlc_instance.media_new('sound.mp3')
    player = vlc_instance.media_player_new()
    player.set_media(media)
    player.play()
    print player.get_state()# Print player's state
```

Comment: until i add time.sleep()
it playes

Answer (score 1):

A slight alternative / method that i just tested and had good results (without needing to worry about the `State.xxxx` types.

This also allowed me to lower the overall wait/delay as i'm using TTS and found i would average 0.2 seconds before `is_playing` returns true

```
p = vlc.MediaPlayer(audio_url)
p.play()
while not p.is_playing():
    time.sleep(0.0025)
while p.is_playing():
    time.sleep(0.0025)
```

The above simply waits for the media to start playing and then for it to stop playing.

**Note:** I'm testing this via a URL / not a local file but was having the same issue and believe this will work the same.

Also fully aware its a slightly older and answered, but hopefully its of use to some.

Answer (score 0):

I.m.o. Flipbarak had it almost right. My version:

```
import vlc, time

vlc_instance = vlc.Instance()
song         = 'D:\\mozart.mp3'
player = vlc_instance.media_player_new()
media  = vlc_instance.media_new(song)

media.get_mrl()
player.set_media(media)

player.play()
playing = set([1])
time.sleep(1.5) # startup time.
duration = player.get_length() / 1000
mm, ss   = divmod(duration, 60)

print "Current song is : ", song, "Length:", "%02d:%02d" % (mm,ss)

time_left = True

# the while loop checks every x seconds if the song is finished.
while time_left == True:

    song_time = player.get_state()

    print 'song time to go: %s' % song_time

    if song_time not in playing:

        time_left = False

    time.sleep(1) # if 1, then delay is 1 second.

print 'Finished playing your song'
```

Comment: while song_time > 0:

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'State' and 'int'

length song : %s State.NothingSpecial

Comment: ..should be fixed now.